# How to Host Leaflet Webmap Using Real Time data on Github

Tags: github, leaflet, mapping

I am trying to publish a web map online that displays real-time air-craft locations. I have used Jupyter notebook to retrieve real-time data from 'airplanes.live' API, and displayed it on a leaflet map using Flask application and html. I basically just want to make this webmap shareable with others, and I heard Github offers free hosting for leaflet maps. However, in this case where the data is real-time, how can I publish it online (using free methods).

I tried making a new Github repository, added the html code along with the Python scirpt as separate files. Opened up the Page and the basemap along with its layers is loaded, but the live aircraft data is missing.

Note: I am very inexperienced in this stuff and have basically gotten this far using ChatGPT and other questions from stack exchange, so any pointers in the right direction are appreciated. The html code is very long, so I can post it if needed.